# Adding more button for <ul> in responsive navigation - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a navigation of 8 items (li), and when resolution gets smaller items drop in a new line. I need to make it so that when an item doesn't fit on a navigation anymore it should put a "MORE" dropdown button on the right side of nav and put the item that doesn't fit in a dropdown.

I don't know how I can do it with the Angular project, I don't need JQuery code.

This is my code:

```
<div id="mainMenu" class="main-menu">
    <ul id="autoNav" class="main-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">about us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">contact</a>
        </li>
        <li id="autoNavMore" class="auto-nav-more">
            <a href="#" class="more-btn">more</a>
            <ul id="autoNavMoreList" class="auto-nav-more-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">policy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
    const $mainMenu = $("#mainMenu");
    const $autoNav = $("#autoNav");
    const $autoNavMore = $("#autoNavMore");
    const $autoNavMoreList = $("#autoNavMoreList");
    autoNavMore = () => {
        let childNumber = 2;

        if($(window).width() >= 320) {
            // GET MENU AND NAV WIDTH
            const $menuWidth = $mainMenu.width();
            const $autoNavWidth = $autoNav.width();
            if($autoNavWidth > $menuWidth) {
                // CODE FIRES WHEN WINDOW SIZE GOES DOWN
                $autoNav.children(`li:nth-last-child(${childNumber})`).prependTo($autoNavMoreList);
                autoNavMore();
            } else {
                // CODE FIRES WHEN WINDOW SIZE GOES UP
                const $autoNavMoreFirst = $autoNavMoreList.children('li:first-child').width();
                // CHECK IF ITEM HAS ENOUGH SPACE TO PLACE IN MENU
                if(($autoNavWidth + $autoNavMoreFirst) < $menuWidth) {
                    $autoNavMoreList.children('li:first-child').insertBefore($autoNavMore);
                }
            }
            if($autoNavMoreList.children().length > 0) {
                $autoNavMore.show();
                childNumber = 2;
            } else {
                $autoNavMore.hide();
                childNumber = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // INIT 
    autoNavMore();
    $(window).resize(autoNavMore);
```

CSS Code:

```
    .main-menu {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    .main-nav {
        display: inline-flex;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .main-nav li a {
        padding: 10px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .more-btn {
        color: red;
    }
    .auto-nav-more {
        position: relative;
    }
    .auto-nav-more-list {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: 0.2s;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: grey;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .auto-nav-more:hover .auto-nav-more-list {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Any help to how I can do it with the Angular project (Typescript)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ng-repeat-start (ngRepeat directive)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Example

```
<header ng-repeat-start="item in items">
    Header {{ item }}

</header>
<div class="body">
  Body {{ item }}
</div>
<footer ng-repeat-end>
  Footer {{ item }}
</footer>
```